# Error con reporte - No puedo eliminarlo

Tags: característica-nueva

Repasando varios comentarios me he encontrado con [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22134/como-puedo-conseguir-una-ruta-guardada-desde-sql-en-byte-y-mostrar-en-datagridvi#comment35257_22134) y por error mío pensando que era un comentario del OP (que su pregunta era en inglés) lo he reportado como tal.

Al momento me he dado cuenta de que no tendría que haberlo reportado ya que no se trata de un comentario del OP sino de un usuario que estaba ayudando al OP que había preguntado en inglés.

Normalmente cuándo propongo cierre tengo la opción de revertir mi voto. ¿Eso no existe con los reportes?

Sería interesante retirar los reportes si la situación ha sido bien por:

- Un error (mi caso)
- Ya se ha solventado (edición pregunta/comentario/respuesta que elimine el motivo)
- Otros que piense la comunidad.

Esto quitaría tiempo que debe invertir la comunidad o el moderador en casos que han sido reportados pero que realmente ya no son necesarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**En el caso de que fuera un fallo muy gordo, simplemente reporta la pregunta para la intervención de un moderador y explica la situación sin problema.**

Ahora bien, en mi opinión el comentario esta correctamente reportado, quizás no pusiste el flag adecuado, pero tanto ese comentario como su respuesta estan obsoletos ya que la pregunta se ha traducido.

---

Los reportes **de los comentarios**, no se pueden cancelar pero se cierran de dos maneras:

- vencen (si, por ejemplo, el comentario reportado es borrado por el usuario)
- los resuelven los moderadores

  - aceptados (se marca como útil y se actua al respecto)
  - rechazados (se cierra por no ser considerado útil y creo que no se realiza ninguna acción)

---

**OTROS TIPOS DE REPORTES**

**SI** que puedes retractarte de cuando **reportas** una **pregunta** o **respuesta**, aunque tiene [bug de traduccion](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/827/falta-traduccion-al-eliminar-un-reporte) `xD`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También cuando emites un voto de **cierre**, de los cuales si te puedes retractar, **PERO NO MODIFICAR**, ya que una vez eliminados no puedes volver a emitir uno diferente! (*pasa algo similar cuando quitas tu voto a un comentario*)

---

Aparte puedes ver tus reportes de meta [aqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/7242) y los del foro normal [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/7242) (si no me he equivocado, el link solo estara disponible para ti)

*PD: si alguien quiere ver los suyos que cambie el literal `numero-de-usuario` del final por su numero de usuario en los siguientes links.*

- META:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/numero-de-usuario
- ES.SO: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/numero-de-usuario

*el numero de usuario sale en la url de tu perfil publico*