# Falta traduccion al eliminar un reporte

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Faltan traducciones  cuando quieres eliminar un reporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por el texto, entiendo que el reporte actual deberia salir debajo del texto en rojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hecho. Estos textos (y otros relacionados) deberían aparecer traducidos tras la próxima compilación.

El reporte pendiente es el que aparece encima del texto rojo (*"se necesita la intervención de un moderador"* en este caso), no falta nada debajo.